# Reactive Extensions for Javascript code examples

Tags: javascript, reactive-extensions-js

Microsoft have published [Reactive Extensions for Javascript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx).
It should make asynchronous (and event based) web-ui programming easy.

There are currently [a video](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FTL01) and [some](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2010/03/21/introduction-to-the-reactive-extensions-for-javascript-jquery-live-event-integration.aspx) tutorials.
But how cool UI could I really make? Do you know any good demos or code examples using rx.js?

Comment: Am I smelling a trend? I'm not sure...

Comment: The real trend behind this is functional programming.

Answer (score 4):

I think this game demo is pretty cool http://juhajasatu.com/worzone/. The source is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/raimohanska/worzone) and the author has a few posts on JavaScript RX on his [blog](http://nullzzz.blogspot.com/2011/02/game-programming-with-rx-js.html)
.